# Анимация Transform в ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

Как анимировать `ScaleTransform` кнопки в шаблоне, и какой тип анимации необходимо применить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно анимировать не всю трансформацию, а свойства `ScaleX` и `ScaleY` этой трансформации. Так как тип этих свойств `double`, соответственно, нужно использовать `DoubleAnimation`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                                From="1" To="2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="scale"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                                From="2" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Button Content="Hello world!" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой основательный ответ!